# A pool didn't find a block since 4 days, is it normal?

Tags: mining-pools

I've been mining on a pool for more than 24h and my balance didn't increase. It is supposed to increase when the pool find a block.
I also remarked that the pool didn't find any block since 4 days, is it bad? Is there a way to estimate the required time for the pool to find a block?

Comment: The pool I am in Monerod normally has a pool hashrate of 1 MH/s. Took about a week to find a block. Not sure how long 1 MH/s normally takes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On typical pools, a miner's pending balance will increase about 4 hours (60 blocks at 2 minutes a block) after the pool finds a block, assuming it is not orphaned in the meantime. When the miner's pending balance reaches the payout threshold (displayed on the payments page on most pools), a chain transfer will occur.

If a pool is unlucky and does not find a block for a while, then the miner's pending balance will obviously not increase, since there is no new monero found. Conversely, a lucky pool finding several blocks quickly will cause the miner's pending balance to increase often.

Pools usually display their estimated time between blocks, near the top center of the main page. This can be calculated by: 2/(H/h) minutes, with H being the network hash rate, and h being the pool's hash rate. This is of course an estimation only. Divide this by 1440 (minutes in a day) to get estimated days between blocks, rather than minutes.

Answer (score 2):

it depends of the pool total hashrate, the pools with low hashrate take more time to mine blocks but when you got payed to got a larger ammount of the block

For example, I am mining currently in a pool with 45Kh, and it take about 7 days to get a block.. Low hashrate pools are great to keep the network descentralise, but it can take time to get payed

Comment: Pedro - New to mining but i want to understand, maybe you can help? 1 - If I am in a large pool and have mined for a time and havent hit the low cap to get paid (.5) and leave, I lose all the work right? 2 - Also I believe in the need to keep the network strong so if i switch to a new or low pool and it takes longer, would i make more in the quicker pool or is it just a matter of time and you'll basically make the same no matter where you mine as long as you stick with it?

Comment: it depends on pool to pool, but I think the majority of the pools only pay you when you get the minimum ammount to withdraw, the people I know use to just keep mining until they get payed and only after that they change... Yes, it depends on the luck of the pool, but in the long run you should earn the same ammount of moneros mining on small or large pools, if everything is ok with the pool