# Why can't a pool find block after the hard fork

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, hard-fork, mining-pool-setup

I know that it's my problem, but I don't have any idea what happened.

Here are my pool stats(private pool):
[image: screen with hashrate and other info about pool]

Here are the stats before the fork:
[image: stats before fork]

Early on, all was good. A few days before the hard fork, I upgraded the monero cli tools to the latest version, and they had been working fine before the night from 15 to 16.

I've not found anything in the monerod logs
(from time to time i'm getting INFO     stacktrace  src/common/stack_trace.cpp:120  Exception: cryptonote::BLOCK_DNE
but it's started much early with upgrade to version v0.11.0.0)

(and I just checked, it's still here).

Version of monerod is ./monerod --version
Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.0.0-release)

So, I don't have question.. I just don't realize what happened, I have not changed anything on the pool server, my miners all are here and working fine and getting updates from the pool ..

I really need any advice.. Thanks!

Comment: Did any of your blocks get rejected after the HF? Also, try compiling a new `monerod` from the release branch (`git clone -b release-v0.11.0.0 https://github.com/monero-project/monero.git`) . Lastly, delete `p2pstate.bin` (it's in `$HOME/.bitmonero`).

Comment: Nope, have not found any rejects after HF, the latest one was September, 14. Thanks, i'm going to try it right now.

Comment: It seems better, after both action i've already found 2 blocks in 4 hours . Thank you. Not sure if it helped or just ... my badluck is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Check your pool logs for "Error submitting block". That's in logs/pool-info.log. If one of those shows up, then a miner found a share matching network difficulty, but the block was rejected.

Then check the same log file for "found at height". If you find any, but your pool did not get the block, then the block got orphaned. This may be due to bad luck (someone else found a block at about the same time), or because your block was invalid, and the network rejected it.

If you find none of those messages, it means you (as in, the miners mining on that pool) were just unlucky.

Comment: Thanks, i've already checked. We did not try to submit any block during period.

Answer (score 0):

At 2.01 MH/sec your pool is currently under 1% of the total network hashrate. It is possible your pool has just been [very unlucky](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5928/a-pool-didnt-find-a-block-since-4-days-is-it-normal) since the fork. Normal variance can cause your expected 4 hour mined block frequency to vary widely at times.

Comment: If i remember right from my school math:
two times of est. time should be enough at least in 95% cases,
3 times of est. time should find block with 99.7%
now it's more than 7 times.. 
I can't be so unlcuky..


But, sure, you are right with really really low chance it's possible..
But i'm still trying to find my mistake..